# Publish a GeoTIFF file as WMS to GeoServer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, qgis-3, wms, geotiff-tiff

I have published the GeoTIFF file which I want to use on the GeoServer without any problems, but when I want to view it on QGIS with a WMS connection, the TIFF file does not come. While uploading to QGIS, it does not give an upload error, but when I click on the incoming link or select the zoom to layer option, I see an empty screen. What could be the reason?

Comment: Kindly explain your question and upload an error message for the same.
Adding Geotiff to Geoserver : 
https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/multidim/adding_data/add_geotiff.html
Accessing Geoserver WMS in QGIS :
https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_wms.html

Comment: I don't get any error messages as I explained above. Everything seems fine but when I call wms my tiff file in QGIS it shows a blank page. I looked at the links you sent many times and I followed the steps there.

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Can your QGIS client see (have access to) the GeoServer service?  Is your data correctly georeferenced? Do GetMap requests work in a browser, (you can use QGIS to discover the request sent to the server).